# iptables error on pptp

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, nat, pptp

```
root@pptp [~]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables: Unknown error 18446744073709551615
```

This is an openVZ box. Is there a way to bypass that?

This is the MASQUERADE that is giving problems I am assuming. new to iptables so is there a way to do this differently

following this guide:
http://blog.secaserver.com/2011/10/install-vpn-pptp-server-centos-6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must [reconfigure the host (hardware) node to load the necessary iptables module(s)](http://kb.parallels.com/en/6816).

In this case it appears you you need `ipt_MASQUERADE`.

Comment: Can that be done in OpenVZ?
what host said: Since MASQUERADE is not possible to virtualized ,
You can configure many to one NAT to an IP alias, using the POSTROUTING instead of MASQUERADE statement

Comment: Oh, this isn't your server, then? Use a VPS provider that doesn't use OpenVZ then.

Comment: Does ipt_MASQUERADE work with OpenVZ? Or am I stuck having to find a XEN. I could ask them again I might have missed sending ipt_MASQUERADE